# Change cart-layout without losing everything after update

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I changed some of the files for the cart of VirtueMart in order to display only the productlist on the first step. I've done this directly inside the `components\com_virtuemart\views\cart\templ`-folder.
But now I've updated VirtueMart and all the design-changes are lost.

Where do I have to save my changes without having to upload them again after every update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change the design of an extension, you should always do it via a template override. This ensures that when the extension is updated, your changes are not lost. Due to you editing the core files for VirtueMart, the update replaced them.

See the link below on how to do template overrides. They are very easy ;)

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whilst this is the correct answer please note there are disadvantages of template overrides as well in terms of that if there is a major extensions update your template override will stop working - or may keep a security flaw that has been fixed! So when you do have template overrides in place you need to make sure that you keep an eye on the changelogs and instructions when template overrides are put in place!